# Requests proxying stop working after update to ember-cli 0.39

Tags: ember-cli

I have just updated a project from ember-cli 0.37 to 0.39 and api requests are not proxied to the rails backend anymore. I've run ember init and update dependencies but it still doesn't work.

- ember-cli 0.39
- ember 1.6.0-beta.5
- ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8
- jquery 2.1.0

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tested with a brand new application and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in master now. See https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1263 for details.

Comment: How to work with ember-cli master https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli#development-hints