# Ember cli .39 not proxying API requests

Tags: ember-cli

Duplicate: [Requests proxying stop working after update to ember-cli 0.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585860/requests-proxying-stop-working-after-update-to-ember-cli-0-39?rq=1)

This is known, fix is [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1263) and currently in master.

---

I just upgraded to ember-cli 0.39, and it seems my API requests aren't being proxied to my (rails) backend. This was working in 0.37.

I run the following commands from the respective directories

```
rails s -p 3900
ember s --port=4900 --proxy=http://0.0.0.0:3900
```

The ember app serves pages that don't hit my API, but when my routes try to fetch a model (I'm using ember-data), the API response is just my ember app's `index.html`. I've set some breakpoints in my rails code, and they're not getting triggered, so I know the API requests aren't being proxied appropriately.

Interestingly, I have a login route I use, and that does seem to proxy back to the rails app. But, whenever I use `store.find('someModel'), the response is the ember app's`index.html` and the app chokes.

As part of upgrading to .39 I changed some of my libs over to the `ember-cli-addons`:

- ember-cli-ember-data
- ember-cli-ember-simple-auth

I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Seems like it could be an ember-data thing.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known, fix is [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1263) and currently in master.